# Isolated points of a subset

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

The title may not be as descriptive as it should be, but I can't think of a better way to phrase how narrow this question is.

This is the theorem from Rudin I'm trying to prove.

> Let $f$ and $g$ be complex continuous functions on a metric space $X$. Then $f + g$, $fg$, and $f/g$ are continuous on $X$.

So, let $x \in X$ be an isolated point. Then the domain of $f + g$ and $fg$ is $X$, so they are automatically  continuous at $x$, which was proved earlier in the chapter.

The difficulty is in the $f/g$ case. Rudin comments that we have to assume the domain of $f/g$ is the set of $x \in X$ such that $g(x) \neq 0$. So call its domain $X'$. If $x$ is an isolated point of $X$, what can I say about it in relation to $X'$? Must it also be an isolated point of $X'$, or is it possibly a limit point?

My attempt at an answer:

If $x$ is an isolated point of $x$, then there exists $r > 0$ such that $N_r (x) \cap X = \{x\}$. Moving to $X'$, we may have either $g(x) = 0$ or $g(x) \neq 0$. If $x \in X'$, then we still have $N_r (x) \cap X' = \{x\}$, because $X' \subset X$ and, otherwise, $N_r (x) \cap X \neq \{x\}$, so $x$ is an isolated point of $X'$. If $x$ isn't in $X'$, it's not an isolated point. I don't think it could be a limit point because,  otherwise, it would be a limit point of $X$ as well. So it's neither in this case.

Comment: Your answer is good. Your argument actually proves something more general: if $A \subseteq B$, then the isolated points of $A$ are a subset of the isolated points of $B$. To put it less formally, taking things out of a set can't increase its set of limit points.

Comment: @RobArthan: that's not a true implication: consider for example $B=[0,2]$ and $A=\{1\}$.

Comment: @GregMartin I'm a bit confused. Is it possible then that taking a subset *can* increase the number of limit points?

Comment: @GregMartin: you are right: my attempt to make a less formal and more snappy statement was wrong. It is however true that if $A \subseteq B$, then the isolated points of $A$ are a subset of the isolated points of $B$, which is the important point here.